# running ant with 64bit Java VM leads to unmappable UTF-8 characters

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, ant

there are some special characters in my java code like this

```
 char c = 'ä';
```

(i know this is bad style and it could be avoided by using the UTF-8 code, but that's not the point of the question)

while this code compiles and runs fine when using java 64bit from with an ide like eclipse, when i try to compile this via ant i get this error:

```
warning: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
```

when running ant with a 32bit java vm there is no warning.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell `javac` what encoding your source files are in. You can do this with the `-encoding` flag or encoding attribute on the javac ant task.

Frankly, just save your source as UTF-8. It's much simpler in the long run.